# Data Types, link object in game inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types, collision-detection

So, I want to put add an object in the Unity inspector so when the "offender" collides with the **gameObject**, it destroys. But, I forgot the "public data type" for that.

If you see any issues in the code, please also tell me.

```
 public int offender;
 private void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision collision)
 {
     if(collision.collider.tag == "Bolt" || collision.collider == offender)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }

 }
```

Comment: You can't compare an integer to a UnityEngine.Collider. It makes no sense

Comment: Thanks, I put "int" as a placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "offender" is a **GameObject**, your variable must be **GameObject** type:

```
public GameObject offender;
private void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.collider.tag == "Bolt" || collision.gameObject == offender)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```